# App Unable to run after adding new custom view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is the error message received in XCode:

```
2016-04-24 19:10:59.020 Bumble Bee[7286:421679] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Bumble_Bee.LoginController 0x7fc723db1ee0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key LoginTextField.'
```

The app was working fine until I added a new Swift file and defined a new custom view controller class named "LoginController".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the missing outlet at Interface. In this case, you may have an `wrong outlet reference` at UIViewController's nib file like this.
Open Interface builder, press right button to check outlets.

[image]

Comment: Thanks BrikerMan!
I right-clicked on my ViewController to check my outlets and indeed one of them were not linked properly in the swift reference file.